# Date binning in swift

Tags: swift, binning

I have the following `struct`:

```
struct ADataPoint: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var time: Int
    var min: Double
    var max: Double
}
```

and the following CustomObject:

```
struct CustomObject {
    var date: Date
    var someValue: Int
}
```

And an `array` of custom objects  with a `date` property. At the moment, I am binning the objects into an `dict` of `arrays`, binned by the `hour` component, like the following:

```
func processedData() -> [ADataPoint] {
    var datapoints = [ADataPoint]()
    
    var binnedDates: [Int: [CustomObject]] = [0: [CustomObject]()]
    var min: Double
    var max: Double
    
    for myObject in myObjects ?? [] {
        let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: myObject.date)
        binnedDates[hour, default: [CustomObject]()].append(myObject)
    }
    
    if(myObjects?.count ?? 0 > 0) {
        for (time, o) in binnedDates  {
            (min, max) = statsForObjects(objects: o)
            datapoints.append(ADataPoint(time: time, min: min, max: max))
        }
    }
    
    return datapoints
}
```

This works. However, is a bit flimsy and inflexible. I may want to separate it for minutes, for e.g. in the future and have to repeat code. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You could pass the date component (Calendar.Component) as a parameter to your function

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions exist for binning time-series data by date. However, a scalable and flexible approach to handling this is to treat it
like an event stream.

Using a Publisher, we can decouple time bin generation from everything else. I don't show the code here, but for my application, I generate a bin
nearest in time for even intervals starting from 00:00:00 in hh:mm:ss time. We can use a protocol to keep the algorithm abstract for the source data and could set a type alias for what is binned.

```swift
protocol Binnable
{
    var startDate: Date { get }
}

typealias Binned = (Date, Binnable)
```

A struct is used to contain the Publishing mechanics.

```swift
import Combine

struct TimeBinner
{
    var timeBinPublisher: AnyPublisher<Binned, Error>?
    private var subject = PassthroughSubject<Binned, Error>()

    init()
    {
        self.timeBinPublisher = subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func sendBinnable(event: Binnable)
    {
        let binDate = // Call a time bin generation function here
        subject.send((binDate, event))
    }
}
```

A subscription can be established at a suitable site to receive binned data.

```swift
let cancellable = timeBinner.timeBinPublisher
    .sink
    { completion in
        // Handle completion
    } receiveValue: 
    { (Binned) in
        // Handle binned data
    }
```

Finally, it is now possible to handle input data isolated from time bin generation and the management of binned data.

```swift
// Examine data to process
for object in data 
{
    timeBinner.sendBinnable(event: object)
}
```

In summary, using Swift abstract data types and Combine, we can have an infrastructure for organizing time-series data into bins marked by date. We can handle many scenarios with an O(n) time complexity. We could also optimize for O(1) lookup time by using a dictionary to store the binned data.

Furthermore, decoupling production from subscription gives us additional benefits, like reacting to changes in the source data or swapping out binning schemes.